# Change the Theme from MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, master-pages, themes

I have a MasterPage that has two image buttons , and two content pages, What i want is that  when an Image button is clicked ----> the theme changes.

I know that MasterPage do not have a "OnPreInit" function and the theme has to be changed inside the "OnPreInit" function...

so is there any workaround for this problem ???

Thanks in advance.

Baher

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I found the Solution for that which is i captured the Image Button clicked and then changed the theme

really easy

Comment: how? this is not helpful at all!

Answer (score 3):

The following is a process used in the Book "Beginning ASP.Net 4 in C# and VB.Net by Imar Spaanjaars". Note that in the book he uses a DropDownList to change the Theme, but I believe the same can be done with an Image button:

1. In the MasterPage add code to the Image Button click event to save the theme name into a cookie. Once the cookie is set you redirect back to the current page.
2. You will need to create a custom BasePage that inherits from the Page class and have all your pages inherit from this BasePage. It is in this BasePage that you will override the Page_PreInit to load the selected theme based on the value of the cookie. The redirect is to run the code in the Page_PreInit to have the Theme change.

I know this might not be the best option, because you will need to change all your pages to inherit from your new BasePage instead of Page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just trying to change the theme from a MasterPage, and all my pages already inherit from it.
I need to do something related to my MasterPage.

thanks.

Comment: You can't change the theme from the MasterPage. It must be done from the content page. The solution Waleed describes will automate this job, introducing a special page controller. This problem is discussed on ASP.NET too: http://forums.asp.net/p/771655/771789.aspx.